# JasperReports plugin for Grails: Getting "No such report spec" Exception

Tags: grails, groovy, jasper-reports, jasper-plugin

I am testing the jaspergrails plugin for Grails.
I am following the tutorial for this plugin. I've created a trivial
jasper report and I've put it under web-app\plugins\jasper-0.9.5\reports\all-races.jasper

I am getting an exception

**Error 500: java.lang.Exception: No such report spec: reports\all-races.jasper or .jrxml**

Any hint why?

thanks a lot in advance.

Luis

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to put the .jasper file under `web-app/reports/` instead.